# Firebase Cloud Function memory limit fail

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I've created a cloud function that aims to take a screenshot of a website when it's added to my websites collection using puppeteer, however I'm constantly hitting a 256mb limit error. I don't know whether the limit is too small or there's an issue with the function and it shouldn't ever be hitting this limit.

```
exports.onWebsiteCreateTakeScreenshot = functions.firestore
    .document('websites/{id}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) =>{
      const webpageDocRef = admin.firestore().collection("websites").doc(context.params.id);
      webpageDocRef.get().then(async (snapshot) => {
        if (!snapshot.empty) {
          const url = snapshot.data()["url"];

          try {
            console.log("Launching puppeteer");
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
              headless: true,
              args: ["--no-sandbox"],
              timeout: 0,
            });
            console.log("puppeteer launch complete");
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.setViewport({width: 640, height: 480});
            await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
            const bucket = admin.storage().bucket("thumbnails");
            const file = bucket.file(context.params.id + ".png");
            const screenshotBuffer = await page.screenshot();
            await file.save(screenshotBuffer);
            await browser.close();
          } catch (e) {
            console.error("Error: " + e);
          }
        } else {
          console.log("Error: No documents found");
        }
      });
    });
```

I noticed that this code block take a long time to complete (minutes rather than seconds):

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
              headless: true,
              args: ["--no-sandbox"],
              timeout: 0,
            });
```

Then I check the logs and see my console log statement in the cloud logs showing that the puppeteer launch did complete, however after this I just see the following error:

> Container worker exceeded memory limit of 256 MiB with 256 MiB used after servicing 2 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class.

There 2 requests, that doesn't seem right although I have had the exact same error stating only 1 request, is this due to the nature of the async functions?

relevant info from functions package.json:

```
"engines": { "node": "16" }, "main": "index.js", "dependencies": { "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2", "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0", "puppeteer" : "^18.2.1", "chromium" : "^3.0.3"
```

Comment: Have you reviewed how much memory Chromium uses? Have you reviewed how little CPU power a Cloud Function receives? Analogy: Your goal is to dig a swimming pool using a teaspoon. I recommend switching to Cloud Run and allocating significantly more resources (CPU and memory) to your application.

Comment: Your comment does not answer my questions. Also, the packages.json details should be in your question and not as a comment.,

Comment: Sorry John I was writing that before I knew anyone responded. Pardon my ignorance as I'm new to firebase, I haven't heard about Cloud Run. Would that be a requirement for enabling more resources? Sounds like it would mean a significant rewrite to my codebase. Is it not possible to just allocate more resources to cloud functions?

Comment: There would be a change to your code. Cloud Functions v2 actually runs on Cloud Functions so you might be able to just reconfigure. As I mentioned review the resource required versus what you are configuring. In summary, your app is crashing due to memory issues (allocate more memory). The long load time is due to limited CPU resources. You are using a teaspoon when you need a backhoe.

Comment: I see, thanks John. I'll look into this more, I hadn't considered the load when creating the function (newbie error I know) as all my other functions have executed reasonably quickly without memory issues, but then I wasn't executing chrome and puppeteer in those.

Comment: Web browsers are **huge** applications compared to the design intent of Cloud Functions. Make sure you also understand how much it will cost to run a browser as a function. a few hundred requests will be cheap, start scanning the Internet and you will spend some money.

Comment: That's a good point, I don't want to incur big costs for what's essentially a minor feature, maybe this isn't such a good idea. I noticed that twitter and whatsapp show screenshots/thumbnails when you post links and thought that would be a cool thing to have, without considering how they go about it, or how much it might cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to configure more memory if you want to use a piece of software like puppeteer.  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation) describes how to set that. For example:

```
exports.onWebsiteCreateTakeScreenshot = functions.firestore
    .runWith({
      // Ensure the function has enough memory and time
      timeoutSeconds: 300,
      memory: "1GB",
    })
    .document('websites/{id}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) =>{
```

Be prepared to also spend more money per CPU-second for this configuration.